# online stream to my own website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hello I am looking for solution that lets to stream video from my webcam to others from my own website.I am using node.js for backend, but the closest npm I found was only simple npm that opens users webcam on website, but in my case I want not to open webcam when I enter webpage, but to see my own stream.I thought about using services like twitch or ustream, but what I need simple stream without play/stop, fullscreen options, that those services provide.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can look [webRTC](https://webrtc.org/start/) to get clear picture of P2P videochat applications. You can find sample app [here](https://github.com/webrtc/samples).